# recording an unknown number of data units in a mysql db table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a flexible loan tracking system and i want it to accommodate for institutions looking to recover loans as instalments from debtors be it monthly, yearly, per school term etc.
I need a way to allow for the configuration of basis of payment, i.e. monthly, yearly etc, so that the system can track payments accordingly. My initial approach was to create a mysql database table with a lot of fields like `term_unit1`, `term_unit2`,`term_unit3` etc with records being the actual period. term_unit1 could be january. 2 could be feb and son on, depending on the size of the payment term. Is there a better way to handle this

Comment: Having numbers in column names is almost every time a bad DB design.

Comment: yes, it is. That's why i'm looking for alternatives

Comment: Your question is too vague for me to answer. What do you want to track. How does your data look like. Hard to give advice on a table design if we only know you have flexibel intervals and not more

Comment: for example. if a debtor pays an instalment for a particular month, to check if they paid for the previous month, its easy, because you know you are dealing with monthly instalments. but in this case the system is flexible hence the use of term_units

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm) should shed some light on normalizing your database.

adding numbers in your columns is not recommended and splitting the term_units to another table would be a much better option.

Comment: thanks, rebirth. i am well-acquitted with the concept of normalization.   lets say you have an input control which captures the # of months a debtor is going to be making instalments and u want to give reference #s to each month he/she is going to be making instalments. how do you go about that

Comment: I'm still not quite sure about understanding the question fully, but what about keeping track of the total debts in one table, and keeping track of the payments in another?